# Not able to get objects,classes and visual fore pages into scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, package.xml, scratch-org-definition-file

I have a developer edition (with devhub enabled) of salesforce and I treid to create the SFDX project using visual code. So far I am able to do following successfully

- Create a new project with manifest file
- Authorize the devhub
- Created default scratch org

Now, when I open the default scratch org for the first time, I can see that it does not have a custom object, apex classes and visual pages in it (which is obvious).

Hence, I need to retrieve all required things from my developer edition (production) into my SFDX project and for that I have tried following commands

> sfdx force:source:retrieve -x .\package.xml

and here is my `package.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
      <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>    
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

After sucessfully executing above command I am still not getting my custom objects in my force-app folder automatically. I also tried following commands but still no luck

> SFDX : Pull from default scratch org
>
> sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdAPIZip -u YorkvilleDefault -k
>   /package.xml

here is my scratch-def.json file

```
{
  "orgName": "YorkvilleDefault",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

to better understand my issue please refer to my image below

[image]

Comment: Did you set the defaultusername? The default username tells the Salesforce CLI, and subsequently the Salesforce Extensions, which org to perform actions against.

Comment: @SarojBera yes that was the reason thanks !!!

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer to the question. Please mark the answer as accepted for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check wheather the default username is set as intended. When you run a CLI command that requires an org connection and you don’t specify a username, the command uses the default. The default username tells the Salesforce CLI, and subsequently the Salesforce Extensions, which org to perform actions against.

Please refere to the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_usernames_orgs.htm). You can set the default username with the `force:config:set` command from your project directory

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=test-wvkpnfm5z113@example.com
```